# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'

Tags: ios, ios9.3, nscoder, initwithcoder

My iOS application is working fine in iOS 10 and newer version. But when I was trying to run my app on iPad mini with iOS version 9.3.2 then Application is crashing.

I am trying to push a view controller and I am using storyboard for all view controllers.

This is my code for push view controller:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PaymentViewcontrolller", sender: self)
```

I am getting this is error in console and application is crashing:

```
2018-10-26 16:21:17.223 Food[592:68727] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2447391b 0x23c0ee17 0x24473861 0x28fbb15f 0x28fbadf5 0x28ea3477 0x28ea3b01 0x28fbb10f 0x28fbb0a1 0x28fbadf5 0x28ea2a0b 0x28d55aa3 0x28b28ffb 0x289eea1f 0x28a06e71 0x28b9d1e5 0x28aab4a7 0x28aab1b5 0x28aab12b 0x289eaa73 0x26a82bcd 0x26a7e375 0x26a7e209 0x26a7d6d1 0x26a7d3a5 0x26a76b2b 0x244356c9 0x244339cd 0x24433dff 0x24383229 0x24383015 0x25973ac9 0x28a57189 0x3d8008 0x2402b873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My Xcode version is 9.4.1 and deployment target is iOS 9.2.

I am not able to figure out what is the issue. Already spent whole day for this.

Comment: Please **read** the error reason. It's quite descriptive.